# Max image size to keep aspect ratio on different desktop screens

Tags: css

What is the image size (height and width) i should create for a background image which will appear on a webpage to render properly on different desktop screens maintaining the aspect ratio? It is a fullpage promo image we just display using css background image property.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely this is one of the [best website](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) for this, there are a lot of techniques

Here is one workaround to achieve this goal:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Try to get more information on that page, it is very useful.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Half of those prefixes aren't even necessary:  http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size (-moz- and -o- prefixes only existed in a single version each)

Comment: You are right but the question doesn't mention which browser version it's using, preventing problems so I decided to put it all.

Answer (score -1):

I would use in your css this

```
.yourclass {
   background-size: cover;
 }
```

This will allow your background to be the size of your div area, so if you set your div as 100% width and height, it will be that on all desktops. It will also not skew, so larger desktops wont make your image look squished.

Comment: could you please explain why the downvote? IMO it's a simple answer that should work in most modern browsers.

Comment: @PA. its not worth it. Moving along.

Comment: Not my downvote but... even though you have the correct property necessary to do achieve the effect the OP is looking for, that's not what they're asking.  They want to know what dimensions to use for the image.